# What's the default Scorer in Sci-kit learn's GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Even if I don't define the scoring parameter, it scores and makes a decision for best estimator, but documentation says the default value for scoring is "None", so what is it using to score when I don't define a metric or list of metrics?

Answer (score 7):

From the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#specifying-an-objective-metric):

> By default, parameter search uses the `score` function of the estimator to evaluate a parameter setting. These are the `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` for classification and `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` for regression...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know they had defaults in function of classificator or regressor, just seeing "score" was driving me mad. Deep dive into he documentation is needed.

Comment: Each estimator's `score` docstring says what it measures. But classifiers and regressors consistently use accuracy and r2, respectively.